# Upper bounds in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to set Upper Bounds for a variable.

```
trait Container {
type A <: Number
def value: A
}
```

Then when I try to get a value for my

```
object AnyNumber extends Container {
def value = 2
}
```

I get this error

```
<console>:25: error: overriding type A in trait Container with bounds <: Number;
 type A has incompatible type
   type A = Int
        ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because `Int` is not a subtype of `Number`, which is the constraint you're placing.

If you want to use type members which are all implicitly convertible to a numeric type, I'd use `Numeric[A]` with an implicit evidence on `value`:

```
trait Container {
  type A
  def value(implicit ev: Numeric[A]): A
}

object AnyNumber extends Container {
  type A = Int
  override def value(implicit ev: Numeric[Int]): Int = 2
}
```

Note I used `Numeric[A]` instead of `Number`, which is the Scala equivalent. Now this will work:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val intRes = AnyNumber.value
}
```

But trying to use this with a `String` won't compile:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val strRes = StringNumber.value
}
```

Results in:

```
Error:(24, 31) could not find implicit value for parameter ev: Numeric[String]
    val strRes = StringNumber.value
```

Answer (score 0):

`scala.Int` only extends `scala.AnyVal`, while your upper bound is `java.lang.Number`.

One way solve is to use `java.lang.Integer` instead of `scala.Int` as it satisfies your boundary (`java.lang.Number`)

eg.

```
trait Container {
  type A <: Number
  def value: A
}

object AnyNumber extends Container {
  type A = Integer
  def value = 2
}

AnyNumber.value shouldBe 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's acceptable for `Container` to be a class instead of trait, the following is close to Yuval's answer but more ergonomic:

```
abstract class Container[A: Numeric] {
  // optional, if you need a type member specifically
  type _A = A
  def value: A
}

object AnyNumber extends Container[Int] {
  def value = 2
}
```

If you want to hide the generic parameter from the API, you can do this:

```
sealed trait Container {
  type A
  val ev: Numeric[A]
  def value: A
}

abstract class ContainerImpl[B](implicit val ev: Numeric[B]) extends Container {
  type A = B
}
```